# How does this javascript callback function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, prototype

can anyone explain line by line, I don't get how this call back and prototype works
especially the function(callback) in js file

```
user.getUsers(function (theUsers) {
     $('#users-table-wrapper').html(user.getATable(theUsers));
});
```

this part in HTML

## Js File

```
function User () {

}
User.prototype.getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'posting.php',
        data: {
            request:'get-users'
        },
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(users){
//            callback(users);
            if (callback) { callback(users); }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my index.html

theUser is not declared but still works. 
when I type funcion (theUser)
as far as I know theUser is a argument or a parameter. It has to be declared somewhere.

## It seems it is neither of them.... how does this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="User.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var user = new User();
            user.getUsers(function (theUsers) {
                $('#users-table-wrapper').html(user.getATable(theUsers));
            });
        });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='main-wrapper'>
        <h3>Users</h3>
       <div id="users-table-wrapper">
       </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the callback? it's a function stored in a variable that gets executed after an event (the ajax success) happens. As far as `theUsers`, that's a parameter that is being passed to the previously mentioned callback.

Answer (score 1):

`theUsers` is a parameter to the anonymous function you provide as a callback:

```
function (theUsers) {
 $('#users-table-wrapper').html(user.getATable(theUsers));
});
```

In the success method of `User.getUsers`, you'll see it works like this:

```
success: function(users){
            if (callback) { callback(users); }
        }
```

Thus, if the AJAX call succeeds, and a callback is defined, the `users` parameter containing the data successfully retrieved is passed as the first argument to the callback function. Since the first argument is named `theUsers` in your anonymous callback definition, that's how it appears inside the method, making itself available for `user.getATable(theUsers)`.

Answer (score 0):

`theUser` is a named argument to your function.

When calling the function, it gets the value of the first parameter passed.
You're calling the function here:

```
callback(users);
```